# spring, hibernate: issue with creating new @Entity model

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, persistence

i am trying to insert data in mysql table testdata.

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;


import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;


import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;


import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

@Entity
@Table(name = "testdata")
public class testdata {


    @Id
    @Column(name = "image_id")
    private String image_id;


    @Column(name = "post_id")
    String post_id;

    @Column(name = "image")
     String image;

    public String getPost_id() {
        return post_id;
    }

    public void setPost_id(String post_id) {
        this.post_id = post_id;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getImage_id() {
        return image_id;
    }

    public void setImage_id(String image_id) {
        this.image_id = image_id;
    }

    public testdata(String post_id, String image, String image_id) {
        super();
        this.post_id = post_id;
        this.image = image;
        this.image_id = image_id;
    }

}

public String getPost_id() {
    return post_id;
}

public void setPost_id(String post_id) {
    this.post_id = post_id;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getImage_id() {
    return image_id;
}

public void setImage_id(String image_id) {
    this.image_id = image_id;
}

public testdata(String post_id, String image, String image_id) {
    super();
    this.post_id = post_id;
    this.image = image;
    this.image_id = image_id;
}
```

}

when i am running my project it gives following exception

```
springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.demo.service.ServiceInterface com.demo.controller.UserController.service; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'service': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.demo.dao.UserDao com.demo.service.ServiceImpl.dao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.demo.dao.UserDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in com.demo.conf.HibernateConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.demo.model.testdata
```

but if i remove the @Entity 
project runs successfully. but data is not inserting.
is it possible to insert data with other methods without hibernate.
if anyone have knowledge about this, i will appreciate.

Comment: consider posting full stacktrace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't specify the `javax.persistence` package for the `Id` annotation.

Replace

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
```

by

```
import javax.persistence.Id;
```

Comment: @Anupam Agnihotri great :)

Comment: @Anupam Agnihotri  "Downvoter It is free ? " is not addressed to you. It is for someone who  downvoted the answer without explanation. With this syntax, he receives the message :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using a **wrong** `@Id` annotation (`import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;`)

Use  `import javax.persistence.Id;` instead